# Is there a way to monitor disk i/o patterns? (i.e. random or sequential i/o?)

Tags: linux, monitoring, disk, iostat

While an application is running, I can monitor disk bandwidth usage using linux tools including dstat.

Now I'd like to know how many sequential or random disk I/Os are occurring in the system.

Does any one know any ways to achieve this?

Comment: Exactly my question. https://serverfault.com/questions/914350/linux-how-can-i-determine-if-an-application-is-doing-sequential-or-random-disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ypu can write your own FUSE filesystem (what you can do using almost any scripting/programming language, even bash) , that would just proxy filesystem calls to pointed filesystem (and eventually translate paths) plus monitor what you minght want to monitor.

Otherwise you might investigate output of `strace` for programs performing I/O calls ofninterest, if possible.